# Why does parallelStream not use the entire available parallelism?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java-stream, fork-join

I have a custom ForkJoinPool created with parallelism of 25.

```
customForkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(25);
```

I have a list of 700 file names and I used code like this to download the files from S3 in parallel and cast them to Java objects:

```
customForkJoinPool.submit(() -> {
   return fileNames
     .parallelStream()
     .map((fileName) -> {
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger("ForkJoinTest");
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("Starting job at Thread:" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        MyObject obj = readObjectFromS3(fileName);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        log.info("completed a job with Latency:" + (endTime - startTime));
        return obj;
     })
     .collect(Collectors.toList);
   });
});
```

When I look at the logs, I see only 5 threads being used. With a parallelism of 25, I expected this to use 25 threads. The average latency to download and convert the file to an object is around 200ms. What am I missing?

May be a better question is how does a parallelstream figure how much to split the original list before creating threads for it? In this case, it looks like it decided to split it 5 times and stop.

Comment: This problem is bad fit for fork-join. For starters, you'd need to be using `ManagedBlocker` since your task is blocking. But, since it's I/O, and not recursively divisible, it's still not a good fit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you doing this with `ForkJoinPool`?  It's meant for CPU-bound tasks with subtasks that are too fast to warrant individual scheduling.  Your workload is IO-bound and with 200ms latency the individual scheduling overhead is negligible.

Use an `Executor`:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import static java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.supplyAsync;

ExecutorService threads = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(25);

List<MyObject> result = fileNames.stream()
        .map(fn -> supplyAsync(() -> readObjectFromS3(fn), threads))
        .collect(toList()).stream()
        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
        .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Thanks. This answers my actual issue. Though I still wonder how parallelStream figures out how much to split and when to stop :)

Comment: @Aishwar - In this case, it doesn't .... and that is the problem.  See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

I think that the answer is in this ... from the `ForkJoinPool` javadoc.

> *"The pool attempts to maintain enough active (or available) threads by dynamically adding, suspending, or resuming internal worker threads, even if some tasks are stalled waiting to join others. **However, no such adjustments are guaranteed in the face of blocked I/O or other unmanaged synchronization**."*

In your case, the downloads will be performing blocking I/O operations.